# Is this a sign I got hacked?

Tags: hacking

I was doing some important stuff on VirtualBox. I reinstalled my Mac brand new, installed VirtualBox from VirtualBox.org, and installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.

After finishing my work I typed `poweroff` (I only have one administrator account). Now  I haven't even installed openssh upon installing Ubuntu, no connection whatsoever to the outside world of this VirtualBox except some very trustworthy installations.

And I get this message:

```
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required
Failed to power off system via login:d: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to open initctl fifo: Permission denied
Failed to talk to init daemon
```

Does that mean somebody else was also using or sneaking into my VirtualBox guest OS?

And by the way, I verified the checksum of the download of my VirtualBox AND of my ubuntu installation!

Comment: Did you rebooted your OS after installing it?

Comment: I just started working immediately after installing Ubuntu on my VirtualBox. I did not reboot it, maybe only if it was required during installation.

Comment: The system needs to be rebooted after installation to compete internal procedures. You aren't hacked as far as i consider. Your device just needs a reboot.

Comment: If your device continues this behaviour, then consider reinstalling the virtual machine.

Comment: No, it just stopped giving these errors after rebooting. But if this is really the case that's reassuring. I think I did my best for security.

Comment: But at some point I just turned off the machine while it was working because of a bug and restarted it.

Comment: There you go, problem solved.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct, so that the issue can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restart the OS after installing to complete necessary configuration. It was just that.

If the message is recurring then you may need to address the issue, but as it was just a one time thing, it is safe to assume it was just because it needed a restart.